# how to place text at any character point

Tags: c#, textbox, format, multiple-columns

I have a text box that I want to place "columns" of data in. I thought I could the text box settings `displayBox.SelectionStart` and `displayBox.SelectionLength` to move the caret and then continue populating data.

Here is my display code for the box:

```
foreach (String line in LoanSort.MyArray)
{ // bringing in lines from my array
  String[] values = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '/'});
  //splitting my lines.
  if (values.GetValue(2).ToString() == "2011")
  {// finding out if the "loan" occured in 2011 and if it did, display...
    displayBox.SelectionStart = 0; displayBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    displayBox.Text += values.GetValue(0).ToString() + "/" +
                       values.GetValue(1).ToString() + "/" +
                       values.GetValue(2).ToString();
    displayBox.SelectionStart = 25; displayBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    displayBox.Text += values.GetValue(3).ToString();
    displayBox.SelectionStart = 65; displayBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    displayBox.Text += values.GetValue(4).ToString();
    displayBox.Text += " " + Environment.NewLine;
  }       
}
```

A date value is contact values.GetValue 0-3. After I print out of the date, I want to then move the cursor the the 25 character spot and output the borrowers lastname, firstname.  But my display does now show a space in characters between the date and name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any specific benefit that mandates using a `TextBox`? You would probably be better served by a `DataGridView`, or at the very least, a `ListBox` with tab-columns. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with meklarian that this is a poor way to achieve your goal, to answer the question you can do the following.

For your example:

```
displayBox.SelectionStart = 65;
displayBox.SelectionLength = 0;
displayBox.Text += values.GetValue(4).ToString();
```

Firstly, you can use `values[4]` instead of `values.GetValue(4).ToString()`.  This will return the string at position 4, so you don't even need to convert it to a string.

You can update at the cursor by using:

```
displayBox.SelectionStart = 65;
displayBox.SelectionLength = 0;
displayBox.SelectedText = values[4];
```

Or simply update the text ignoring the cursor altogether:

```
displayBox.Text = displayBox.Text.Insert(65, values[4]);
```

A better way is to use string formatting.  This code does a couple of things.  The first `string.Format` formats elements 0, 1 and 2 of `values`, then pads them to 25 character's wide.  The second `string.Format` formats elements 3 and 4 of `values`.  The term `,-40` instructs the format to be 40 characters wide, left justified.  We couldn't use that on the first `string.Format` because we were padding the result of several elements, not just one element.

```
displayBox.Text +=
    string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", values).PadRight(25) +
    string.Format("{3,-40}{4} ", values) +
    Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: i used a string.Format also within a string builder.  it seems to have worked nicely. i hope this is the only project i do like this that requries the user of a text box.  :) thanks guys for your input.